# How I use make provider directives INSIDE an ng-template?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use angular material's `mat-tree` in conjunction with an `ng-template`.  If I do:

```
<ng-template #row let-node="node">{{ node.name }}</ng-template>
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>
    <div *ngTemplateOutlet="row; context:{node: node}"></div>
  </mat-tree-node>
  <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChildren">
    <div *ngTemplateOutlet="row; context:{node: node}"></div>
  </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

This works fine, but as soon as I have the `ng-template` make use of directives, such as `matTreeNodeToggle`, for example:

```
<ng-template #row let-node="node"><div matTreeNodeToggle>{{ node.name }}</div></ng-template>
```

then I get an R3InjectorError `NullInjectorError: No provider for CdkTree!`

How do I make the providers of my component available within the context of the `ng-template`?

Comment: forgot to import `CdkTreeModule`?

Comment: @AntonMarinenko how do I import that within the `ng-template`?  Like I said, everything works fine if I don't use `ng-template`.

Comment: Just import it to your module with this component.

Comment: If that were the problem, it would not be working when I don't use `ng-template`..  Regardless, I did add it to my imports and it behaves the same.

Comment: I am baffled that I am apparently the only person on the planet who's encountered this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem seems to be that Angular does some weird ass shit with mat-tree imports in the testing environment.

For the life of me, I cannot get my test to run, that uses `<mat-nested-tree-node>`. My component is super dumb: it has 30 lines of code, has one event emitter and the only thing it does is to create a listener on ngOnInit, destroy the listener on ngOnDestroy and emit (an empty value) when something is clicked.

I have tried everything and even the smoke test does not work. I have dumbed down the template to **only** be `<mat-nested-tree-node></mat-nested-tree-node>`.

When my imports in the test look like this:

```js
imports: [
  TranslateModule.forRoot(),
  MatIconModule,
  RouterTestingModule
],
```

I will get `ERROR: 'NG0304: 'mat-nested-tree-node' is not a known element`.

Once I import MaterialModule or MatTreeModule, my test will immediately break completely with

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[CdkTree -> CdkTree]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for CdkTree!
```

Trying to import CdkTreeModule changes nothing at all, and trying to add a mocked provider for CdkTree only results in `Error: Incorrect tree structure containing detached node.`

I have no idea what is happening, why it is happening and how the frick the actual implementation outside of the tests even works.

For now I have mocked away `<mat-nested-tree-module>` in my tests by creating an empty component within my test and using it and neither import MaterialModule nor MatTreeModule. Like so:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'mat-nested-tree-node',
  template: ''
})
class MatNestedTreeNodeMockComponent {}

(...)

await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ SomeModulesNestedItemComponent, MatNestedTreeNodeMockComponent ]
})
.compileComponents();
```

**Update:**
I have done more testing and I found this very annoying and stupid reason for why this doesn't work (and which is probably also your problem): As soon as everything is not wrapped around a `<mat-tree>` without anything in between whatsoever, things seem to be broken.

I have submitted a bug with Angular about this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/49950